# PostgreSQL connection refused when running docker image in Cloud Build

Tags: postgresql, docker, google-cloud-build

I am using Cloud Build to run unit tests on a simple Python script which interacts with a PostgreSQL server.

For the unit test, I run the Postgres Docker image and connect via psycopg2.

However, I get the following error

```
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Cannot assign requested address
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

My base image is postgresql_utils_unit_test_python3.9

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

# install docker from https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/
# required for postrgresql-utils unit testing
RUN apt update -qq && \
    apt install -y -qq postgresql libpq-dev python3-dev gcc ca-certificates curl gnupg lsb-release && \
    mkdir -m 0755 -p /etc/apt/keyrings && \
    curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg && \
    echo \
        "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian $(lsb_release -cs) stable" \
        | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null

RUN apt update -qq && \
    apt install -y -qq docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin
```

my cloud build config is

```yaml
steps:
  - id: test and build 3.9
    name: postgresql_utils_unit_test_python3.9
    script: |
      #!/bin/bash
      docker pull postgres
      docker run --detach --name pgsql-dev -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test1234 -e POSTGRES_DB=control_manager -p 3205:5432 postgres
      pip install .
      pip install -r tests/requirements.txt
      python -m pytest tests
```

Connection to the postgres server is

```py
connection = "user=postgres password=test1234 host=localhost port=3205 dbname=control_manager"
db = connect(connection)
```

at `db = connect(connection)` line I see the error.

I have tried connecting via the IP from `docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' <<Container ID>>` but that also didn't work.

Here is the relevant container from `docker container ls`

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                                                                        COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                  PORTS                                       NAMES
d1247ce4db4c   postgres                                                                                                     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 seconds ago    Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:3205->5432/tcp, :::3205->5432/tcp   pgsql-dev
```

here is the hosts file from the container

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.3  d1247ce4db4c
```

Comment: Can you check this documentation on [fixing PostgreSQL connection refused](https://bobcares.com/blog/postgressql-connection-refused/) as it may have several factors why you encounter this kind of error?